# Как передать скрытую информацию при перенаправлении на другую страницу?

Tags: django, веб-программирование, webview

Реализую регистрацию на сайте с подтверждением почты на django через отправку кода(токены, встроенные в джанго не интересуют)
Столкнулся с такой проблемой - после заполнения пользователем формы, я перенаправляю его на другой url для подтверждения почты, но вся информация из request.POST исчезает и я не могу сохранить эти данные с формы.

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'otherstest@yandex.ru'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'base/registration.html', context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            if RegistrationView.is_registered(data['email']):
                return render(request, 'base/registration.html',
                              context={'form': form, 'message': 'User with this email is already registered'})
            else:
                code = RegistrationView.send_code(data['email'])
                request.POST = request.POST.copy()
                request.POST['code'] = code

                redirect_url = reverse('verify')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)


        else:
            return render(request, 'base/registration.html', context={"form": form})

    @staticmethod
    def is_registered(username):
        if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) > 0:
            return True
        return False

    @classmethod
    def send_code(cls, email):
        code = randrange(1000, 9999)
        send_mail(
            subject='Code for registration in the Others',
            message=f"{code} - your verification code",
            from_email=cls.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=[email]
        )
        return code


class VerifyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'base/verify.html')

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        if data['code'] == data['user_code']:
            User.objects.create_user(username=data['email'], password=data['password'], first_name=data['name'],
                                     last_name=data['surname'])
            user = authenticate(username=data['emai'], password=data['password'])
            login(request, user)
            HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'base/verify.html',
                          context={'message': 'Invalid code'})
```

Я генерирую код с помощью библиотеки random и отправляю его на почту, предполагается, что пользователь перенаправляется с страницы registration на страницу verify, вводит там код, отправляет, в случае если код правильный я создаю и логиню пользователя, иначе - высылаю шаблон с информацией о неверном коде.
code - мой сгенерированный код
user_code - код получаемый от пользователя на странице verify, при отправке post запроса.
Каким образом мне сохранить данные полученные с страницы registration, чтобы использовать их на странице verify?
В какой-то момент пришла идея создать экземпляр VerifyView и вернуть его в return, но как не странно - это не увенчалось успехом, потому что перенаправления не произошло.
Как реализована моя идея на обычных сайтах?
В принципе, я могу обойтись без перенаправления различая между собой post запросы на странице регистрации. Если именно таким образом представлена реализация на сайтах или это единственный выход, то дайте знать.

Comment: «Обычные сайты» просто сразу создают пользователя да и всё, а по коду просто включают доступ к заранее созданному пользователю

Comment: andreymal прав) проще потом удалить не активированных пользователей, если очень нужно, чем заморачиваться с вашим видением вопроса) верифай код на почту может вообще не дойти, по каким-то причинам) на всех известных мне платформах используется именно метод подтверждения) в любом случае данные придется куда-то сохранять

Comment: @andreymal включают доступ? не могли бы вы пояснить, что это значит?

Comment: В контексте Django это может быть например [User.is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active)

Comment: @andreymal а как в таком случае бороться с аккаунтами-однодневками ? В критичной ситуации пользователь заполнил форму регистрации, но почту не подтвердил, при этом запись в бд уже ушла, потому что мы создали пользователя. Допустим, пользователь решил допройти регистрацию заново под той же почтой, запись в бд уже есть, ему попросту не даст создать аккаунт, как быть в этом случае ? Удалять записи в бд при запросе если is_active = false? это разве не затратно?

Comment: Раз все так делают, то видимо не затратно. Впрочем, есть и альтернативный вариант — положить данные для регистрации в отдельную модель, а по коду уже взять данные из этой модели и создать пользователя (и после этого не забыть удалить все данные для регистрации с той же почтой и/или тем же ником, если вдруг пользователь пытался зарегистрироваться на одну и ту же почту или ник несколько раз)

Comment: @andreymal Хорошая задумка насчет отдельной модели, но в этом случае мы так же столкнемся с проблемой, что данные извлекать по коду не совсем хорошо, может возникнуть ситуация, что два пользователя получат один и тот же код, хотя в принципе это исключение можно обработать уже в коде, спасибо!

Comment: Одних и тех же кодов быть не должно, генерируйте их достаточно длинными и достаточно случайными, чтобы вероятность повторов (и тем более вероятность намеренного подбора кода злоумышленником) свести к практическому нулю

Comment: @andreymal в общем, решил релизовать вашу первоначальную идею с is_active, столкнулся с первоначальной проблемой, при is_active = false django не логинит пользователя в сессии, из-за этого данные пользователя никак не достать, потому что не известно, что это за пользователь. Достать конечно можно, но только в одном случае, опять же, если искать по коду, полученному из post при верификации.

Comment: Проще всего конечно просто отображать дополнительное поле в форме регистрации для кода после ее отправки, таким образом повторно придут и данные с формы, по котором можно достать запись из бд... Но так не хочется искать легких путей)

Comment: Очевидно доставать по коду, все ж так и делают